# Why doesn't my method of integration work in this question?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I split $x^2=8y$ into $x=\sqrt{8y}$ and $x=-\sqrt{8y}$ and subtracted the latter from the former.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iU9A.jpg)

And I failed the next question too.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt2GO.jpg)

I had $ y= \sqrt{16-x^2}$ and To get the area of the 3d cross section I squared it and multiplied by a quartet before integrating from $ -4 $ to $ 4. $

I understand why  different methods are correct, But I dont know why the way im doing it is wrong.

Comment: You are correct that $\sqrt{8y}$ and $-\sqrt{8y}$ are the two values of $x$ for a given $y$ in the first problem, but you don't say how this relates to the _volume_ that was requested. In the second problem, you have an isoceles right triangle with hypotenuse $2y$; why do you multiply by "a quartet"?

Comment: I got the area of the cross section of the second question by multiplying the root of2/2 of the hypotenuse by the other side of the isocelese which is also root2/2* hyptenuse and then multiplied it by a half. (b*h)/2 which left me with 1/4* hypotenuse^2. They worked the volume out the same way as me for both questions, they just defined x and y respectively in each question differently.

But from what I can see both my method and theirs are correct, however mine cannot be due to getting an incorrect answer.

Comment: It is correct that the area is $\frac14(\mathit{hypotenuse})^2,$ but the hypotenuse is $2y,$ not $y.$ So you have introduced a factor-of-$4$ error.

Comment: I also forgot to integrate with 2roots rather than 1 in the furst question , so a factor of 4 error again, thanks.